# Pdf creation/manipulation from classic asp?

Tags: pdf, asp-classic, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'd like to do the following tasks on pdf files from classic asp

1. get page count
2. split pages
3. save splitted pdf

Is there a nice and easy library available?

-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) with great success.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problems to use a commandline tool with `server.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")` then I would recommend [PDFTK - The PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdfhacks.com/pdftk/). I used it in a project with PDFs up to 500 MB  without any problems.

This is what PDFTK can do for you:

- Merge PDF Documents
- Split PDF Pages into a New Document
- Rotate PDF Pages or Documents
- Decrypt Input as Necessary (Password Required)
- Encrypt Output as Desired
- Fill PDF Forms with FDF Data or XFDF Data and/or Flatten Forms
- Apply a Background Watermark or a Foreground Stamp
- Report on PDF Metrics such as Metadata, Bookmarks, and Page Labels
- Update PDF Metadata
- Attach Files to PDF Pages or the PDF Document
- Unpack PDF Attachments
- Burst a PDF Document into Single Pages
- Uncompress and Re-Compress Page Streams
- Repair Corrupted PDF (Where Possible)

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for "ActiveX PDF".  In Classic ASP you can create any ActiveX object like so:

```
Set o = Server.CreateObject("PDF.ClassName")
o.DoSomething
```

So if you find a control that is an ActiveX control, you'll be able to use it.